# How does Windows LIve ID work?

Tags: authentication, openid, windows-live-id, liveid

I happens to find this [nice article](http://tinisles.blogspot.com/2008/02/how-does-openid-work.html) explaining how OpenID works. Clearly, OpenID consumer and OpenID server transfer information through URL query string.

I'm wondering how Live ID accomplish similar functionality. It seems the info is not exchanged through query string in URL. And, since Live ID login server have different domain name from consumer domain, it is not applicable to transfer info through cookie.

I tried to google tutorial of Live ID, but the result is full of jargon and hard to understand. Is there any easy-to-understand tutorial about How Live ID works?

Comment: hmmm... you just gave me a good idea for a blog article! :)

Comment: Cool! looking forward to your blog post.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to tell you that Microsoft has signed as the OpenID Provider but didn't implemented the same. Live ID is different from OpenID, but LiveID Supports OAuth and thus use OAuth method of LiveID. Don't know how much they will take to implement the OpenID